# Does the nut experience the same forces a bolt experiences but in opposite directions as reaction forces?

Tags: fasteners, machine-elements

More specifically, if I have an eye bolt being used to lift a body, I can find the various stresses acting on the bolt, but I want to know what happens to the threaded area of the body where the eye bolt is fastened.

Will it be the same thing just in the opposite direction, as in the same shear force? And the area experiencing it would also effectively be the same?

Comment: For practical purposes, I think so. Maybe imagine if due to very slight difference in form, or due to deformation under working load, the contact line is biased toward or away from the symmetry axis - thus closer to the root of male/female and opposite for its counterpart. Might affect stress on threads? Would it make a difference in application? I doubt it. Screws are designed so that it isn't the threads that fail, if used properly. Instead, typically fail in male part, especially near head of a bolt (due to stress concentration??)... Relevant exception is if female material is much weaker.

Comment: @PeteW well yea that very exception is what I'm inquiring about. So what I'm considering is a heavy load being lifted by an eye bolt. Now I can find the calculations needed for the bolt but I need to check if the material being lifted can handle the shearing. Hence the question about what force the nut will experience.

Comment: oh ok. there's a RoyMech page that addresses that, sort-of. Basically they suggest scaling the typical thread engagement by the ratio of material strength of the male/female materials. They are still talking about a typical "clamping" setup, vs maybe what you have.  but you can see the reasoning for the thread stripping scenario - simple shear calculation but assuming the first  N threads take most of the load
https://roymech.org/Useful_Tables/Screws/Thread_Calcs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following image shows the interaction between the thread of the bolt and the "nut"

[image]

**Figure: source[Taylor_Tharp](http://ffden-2.phys.uaf.edu/webproj/211_fall_2016/Taylor_Tharp/TAYLOR_THARP_PHYSICS_OF_BOLTS/TAYLOR_THARP_3_FRICTION_AND_TORQUE.html)**

Yes the forces are equal and opposing (although they are distributed along the contact surface)

The direction of the forces is normal to the contact surface and it can therefore be decomposed to *parallel* and *lateral* to the axis of the bolts.

The parallel forces are the shear forces.

Answer (score 2):

The bolt threads when engaged to the nut hole cause local stresses like bearing and shear that create punching shear and bending moments in the nut. The bearing and stress in the nut are varied depending on the stiffness of the bolt, the first threads taking larger loads.

Depending on the size and thickness of the washer or connection opening, these can be the critical stresses in the nut.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to understand what these local forces are so I can find these critical stresses. Hence my question.

Answer (score 1):

When you fix any other face of the body to ground, for example, and then try to apply some forces/moments onto the bolt, then yes the threaded region of the bolt will experience the forces/moments in the opposite direction of the applied loads/moment (this is because the hole's wall is applying equal but opposite load onto the threaded region). While the hole's wall will experience the forces/moments in the same direction as the applied loads/moments. If you consider the bolt and body now as a single unit (since they are glued), then the face of the body which is being fixed to the ground will experience forces/moments opposite to that of applied.

Shear force, or any other force, well it depends how you define the shear force? acting parallel to the faces on threaded region? Well, there might be some forces acting perpendicular to the faces on threaded region as well. But overall, the net force experienced by the threaded region will be the same as the applied load, and in the opposite direction.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I thought this would be the case but needed to be sure.